# Slice FLAC file into 5 second segments

Tags: ffmpeg, flac

I have a FLAC audio file that I want to slice into 5 second segments.  I don't need to resample or change the data in any way.

What tools/libraries are there for this? Should I be looking at ffmpeg?  I actually want to create a HLS stream so a tool that would do that would be a bonus but if I can simply chunk the audio data I can create the playlist myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment):

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -f segment -segment_time 5 output_%03d.flac
```

- In this example outputs will be named `output_001.flac`, `output_002.flac`, etc.
- Add `-reset_timestamps 1` if your need to reset timestamps at the beginning of each segment.
- Since you asked there is also the [HLS muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls), but that's a different topic from the question title.

Comment: That's great, thank you.  I posted another question related to what I'm trying to achieve WRT HLS here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584762/create-hls-audio-stream-from-flac