# Create HLS audio stream from FLAC

Tags: http-live-streaming, flac

I have a FLAC file that contains a single song.  I want to create a HLS stream with the best quality stream being FLAC (matching the input so just pass-through but chunked) followed by AAC-LC 320, 160 and 96Kbps.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The following command is a good point to start:

```
./ffmpeg -i my.flac -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -c:a:0 flac -c:a:1 aac -c:a:2 aac -c:a:3 aac -b:a:1 320k -b:a:2 160k -b:a:3 96k -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -var_stream_map "a:0 a:1 a:2 a:3" stream_%v.m3u8
```

Some explanation:

- `-map 0:a` adds the audio input 4 times (0:a means from the first input file (0) the audio stream)
- `-c:a:0` sets the codec for each stream (0 = flac; 1+2+3 for aac)
- `-b:a:0` sets the bitrate for each steam (1-3 for aac 320/160/96kbits)
- `-f hls` because you want HLS
- `-hls_playlist_type vod` to keep all segments of the HLS stream
- `-master_pl_name master.m3u8` name of the master playlist (contains all 4 streams)
- `-var_stream_map "a:0 a:1 a:2 a:3"` add all 4 audio streams to the output
- `stream_%v.m3u8` name of the HLS playlist for each stream (with the placeholder `%v` for the stream variant